# Foreach. Array inside another array?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to get some values with foreach but I just can't. I've searched some hours but nothing worked.

I have this php code:

```
<?php
$summonerId = $summonerdata->$summoner->id;
$data_runes = $leagueclass->getsummonerdata($summonerdata->$summoner->id, 'runes');
foreach ($data_runes["pages"]["name"] as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

But it doens't works too. When I use "print_r($data_runes, true)" I get this: http://pastebin.com/SgejeFnJ (I've used pastebin because the code is too long).

`[summonerId]` is the player Id. `[pages]` is the rune pages he has in the game.

I want to take every page with their respective name, `runeslotId` and `runeId`. Could you help me?

Comment: <br> has to be echo'd. Just writing it in the php code will result in a parse error.

Comment: Note for people answering, his code got garbled while posting - current version represents his actual code.

Comment: side-note: the output of `var_export(...)` is more useful than `print_r()` for example data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach ($data_runes["pages"] as $page) {
     foreach($page as $key => $value){
         echo $key; // here the index
         echo $value['name']; // or other field $value['current'], $value['id'],... 
      }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details to the OP on what does what (at least add a line into the loop to show the use in this context)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the array/stdClass construct is

```
summoner
  summonerid
  page1
    pageid
    pagename
    slot1 ...
      slotid
      runeid
    slotn
  pagen
    pageid
    pagename
    slot1 ...
    slotn
```

I hope the example is self-explanatory (print_r($data_runes) matches the output posted on pastebin)

```
<?php
$data_runes = getData();

// each top-level element in $data_runes correspondes to one summoner instance
foreach( $data_runes as $summoner ) {
    echo 'summonerid:', $summoner->summonerId, "\r\n";

    // each summoner instance has an element pages -> array(page0 ... pagen)
    foreach( $summoner->pages as $page ) {
        echo '  pageid:', $page->id, "\r\n";
        echo '  name:', $page->name, "\r\n";
        echo '  current:', $page->current, "\r\n";
        // each page instance has an element slots -> array(slot0....slotn)
        foreach( $page->slots as $slot ) {
            echo '    [ runeSlotId:', $slot->runeSlotId;
            echo ' , runeId:', $slot->runeId, " ]\r\n";
        }
    }
}

function getData() {
    return (object)array(
        '36637645' => (object)array(
            'summonerId' => '36637645',
            'pages' => array(
            '0' => (object)array(
                'id' => '39056930',
                'name' => 'Adc',
                'current' => '1',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5337',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5337',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5337',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            '1' => (object)array(
                'id' => '39056931',
                'name' => 'SAPP',
                'current' => '',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5367',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5367',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5367',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            '2' => (object)array(
                'id' => '60104899',
                'name' => 'Sweg',
                'current' => '',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5273',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5316',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5297',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5357',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5357',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5357',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            '3' => (object)array(
                'id' => '60104900',
                'name' => 'Ad cdr',
                'current' => '',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            '4' => (object)array(
                'id' => '99301020',
                'name' => 'Ad Cdr 7.50%',
                'current' => '',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5295',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5335',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            '5' => (object)array(
                'id' => '99301021',
                'name' => 'Ad mr lifesteal',
                'current' => '',
                'slots' => array(
                    '0' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '1',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '1' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '2',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '2' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '3',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '3' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '4',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '4' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '5',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '5' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '6',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '6' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '7',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '7' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '8',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '8' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '9',
                        'runeId' => '5245',
                        ),
                    '9' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '10',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '10' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '11',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '11' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '12',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '12' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '13',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '13' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '14',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '14' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '15',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '15' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '16',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '16' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '17',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '17' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '18',
                        'runeId' => '5317',
                        ),
                    '18' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '19',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '19' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '20',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '20' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '21',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '21' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '22',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '22' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '23',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '23' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '24',
                        'runeId' => '5289',
                        ),
                    '24' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '25',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '25' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '26',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '26' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '27',
                        'runeId' => '5290',
                        ),
                    '27' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '28',
                        'runeId' => '5412',
                        ),
                    '28' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '29',
                        'runeId' => '5412',
                        ),
                    '29' => (object)array(
                        'runeSlotId' => '30',
                        'runeId' => '5412',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

prints

```
summonerid:36637645
  pageid:39056930
  name:Adc
  current:1
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5337 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5337 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5337 ]
  pageid:39056931
  name:SAPP
  current:
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5367 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5367 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5367 ]
  pageid:60104899
  name:Sweg
  current:
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5273 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5316 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5297 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5357 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5357 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5357 ]
  pageid:60104900
  name:Ad cdr
  current:
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5335 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5335 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5335 ]
  pageid:99301020
  name:Ad Cdr 7.50%
  current:
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5295 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5335 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5335 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5335 ]
  pageid:99301021
  name:Ad mr lifesteal
  current:
    [ runeSlotId:1 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:2 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:3 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:4 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:5 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:6 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:7 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:8 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:9 , runeId:5245 ]
    [ runeSlotId:10 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:11 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:12 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:13 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:14 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:15 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:16 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:17 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:18 , runeId:5317 ]
    [ runeSlotId:19 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:20 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:21 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:22 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:23 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:24 , runeId:5289 ]
    [ runeSlotId:25 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:26 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:27 , runeId:5290 ]
    [ runeSlotId:28 , runeId:5412 ]
    [ runeSlotId:29 , runeId:5412 ]
    [ runeSlotId:30 , runeId:5412 ]
```